# Insert excel function from birt report designer

Tags: excel, function, insert, birt

I am generating excel reports using birt, is there a way to pass an excel function through the birt designer. For example, in the generated excel report I want to store =A1+B1 in the C1 cell. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Add the two cells and put in the another column and make that column visibilty into **true** for html/pdf...but for excel make into **false** so you can have your result values in excel..